# Button Click getting called without being emitted in the child component

Tags: angular

I am creating a custom component to simulate the split button. I've everything in place and seems working as expected. However, the `app-button` click event is called in the parent component without that being emitted in the child component. How that works?

In the below example and in the button component, nothing is emitted but the parent click event parentClick() getting called. How? Maybe, my assumption is wrong with `EventEmitter`. I understood in the way that only the child component emits the click then the parent pick it up?

```
@Output() clickEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()
```

**Split-Button.Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-split-button',
  template: `<div class="btn-group dropdown" dropdown triggers="hover" #dp="bs-dropdown" (mouseleave)="dp.hide()">
              <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-success rounded-0 dropdown-toggle"
                      aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
                Save <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 rounded-0 bg-success m-0 p-0" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" (mouseleave)="dp.hide()">
                <ng-content select="app-button"></ng-content>
              </div>
            </div>`
})
export class SplitButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

**Button Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    template: `<div>
                <button type="button">
                    {{buttonText}}
                </button>
            </div>`
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() buttonText: string; 

    ngOnInit() {

    }

//Here in the component, nothing is emitted but the parent click event parentClick() getting called. How?!
}
```

**Parent-Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-split-button>
              <app-button buttonText="Action1" (click)="parentClick()"></app-button>
            </app-split-button>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Test Component';

   ngOnInit() {
  }

  parentClick() {
    console.log("parentClick");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, for example on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are using the angular directive `click` in `<app-button buttonText="Action1" (click)="parentClick()"></app-button>` which listens to click event from the DOM, it has nothing to do with the parent-child relationship here, if the `app-button` is clicked, `parentClick()` method is called.

To learn how `@Input / @Output` works, please refer this https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

The DOM structure of the `AppComponent` would be

```html
<app-root>
  <app-split-button>
    <div class="btn-group dropdown" dropdown triggers="hover" #dp="bs-dropdown" (mouseleave)="dp.hide()">
      <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-success rounded-0 dropdown-toggle"
        aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
        Save <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 rounded-0 bg-success m-0 p-0" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
        (mouseleave)="dp.hide()">
        <app-button buttonText="Action1" (click)="parentClick()"></app-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-split-button>
</app-root>
```

So naturally it will react to the standard [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event from the DOM.